# React Components - Where to store HTML Templates

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Complete newbie to React and trying to find out how to load the HTML for components rather than inserting it directly in the render method. For example

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Login extends Component { 

  render() {
    return (
       <!-- how can I provide a link to the HTML template for here? -->
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The idea is that you put the HTML in the render method, e.g. using JSX: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React does not have HTML. The JSX that you write in the render method is actually compiled into JavaScript. At the core, React components are all JavaScript. The styles are also inline. Componentisation is neat in React because HTML, CSS, JavaScript (interactions) are all in one place, as JavaScript.

To insert raw HTML, React has an attribute [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html).

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want some type of organization, you can use variables to set the html and then assign that to the render functionalty, but React does not use html templates

```
var hello = React.createClass({
    render: yourVariable
});
```

Comment: To be clear, "yourVariable" needs to be a function that returns JSX (not a string in HTML format).

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confused about how JSX works.Just in case, I want to clarify that JSX is what they call "syntactic sugar", that turns React methods such as React.createElement into that XML like syntax. For instance:

```
var Nav;
// Input (JSX):
var app = <Nav color="blue" />;
// Output (JS):
var app = React.createElement(Nav, {color:"blue"});
```

(from the React [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html))

So, to the best of my knowledge, the JSX syntax actually belongs in the render method. If what you are really looking for is the best way to separate and reuse purely presentational code, you should read on separating your app into Container and Presentational components

https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.dzjqc8yrn
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.mn9nf6lz6

Stateless/Presentational/Dumb Components are just functions that return JSX. So you could have your Template component:

```
import React from 'react';
//you need to import React to use JSX, as it will be expanded into React.createElement calls...
function Template(props){
    return ( 
       //...your template here... 
     );
}
```

And then your class

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Login extends Component { 

  render() {
    return (<Template {...props}/>);
  }
}
}
```

Makes sense?